# How can i print and return a value from a function in python?

Tags: python, function

i cant figure out how to make a return value from a function return and print,
Example

```
def exe(a,b):
    if a == b:
        return 1
```

How would i get that 1 to print as well as return? Thanks in advance. I know its a stupid question and pretty useless, but im pretty sure it can be done and not knowing how is driving me nuts.

Comment: Include well formatted code for the question.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formatted code piotr. I was just throwing out a quick example in case people didnt understand the question. How bout this, dont use poorly formatted smartass remarks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple statements, but the "return" ends the function.

Print is just a statement when combined with the expressions (the stuff to the right of it) (in Python 2) that sends to expressions to standard out, (stdout), typically the console. In Python 3, print is a function, and so it's preferable to use print as a function in modern Python.

So you want print to come before return.

```
def exe(a,b):
    if a == b:
        print(1)
        return 1
```

Comment: In Python 3, print is not a statement but a function, and it should be `print(1)`. New Python 2.7 code is probably best written with a future transition in mind, and if the file starts with `from __future__ import print_function`, Python 2.7 has the 3 behavior. Don't use print as a statement anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
def exe(a,b):
    return 1 if a == b else None

print exe(1,1)
```